# Failing to connect with mongo using heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am in the process of deploying my app in heroku however I have ran into some difficulties. I am able to connect to my mlab mongo database on my local computer and using the heroku local web (although for reasons I have not looked into yet I cannot query the database). Below is my error from the heroku logs:

```
017-06-30T03:18:42.576989+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:377
2017-06-30T03:18:42.576990+00:00 app[web.1]:           throw err
2017-06-30T03:18:42.576991+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2017-06-30T03:18:42.576996+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
2017-06-30T03:18:42.576997+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:328:35)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.576998+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.576999+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.emit (events.js:210:7)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.576999+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577000+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:318:30)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577001+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577001+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.emit (events.js:213:7)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577002+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:177:49)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577003+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577004+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577004+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577005+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:62:8)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.577007+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
2017-06-30T03:18:42.677447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-30T03:18:42.671887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

My code is as follows (I have removed some stuff just to try and keep it brief):

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoStore = require('connect-mongo/es5')({ session: expressSession });

require('./models/users_model.js');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;


var MONGOLAB_URI = "mongodb://username:password@ etc."; 

var connection = mongoose.connect(MONGOLAB_URI, {useMongoClient: true},function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connection established to', MONGOLAB_URI);
  }
});
```

Comment: The error being thrown is `failed to connect to server [localhost:27017]` so therefore it is not using the mlab connection string. Seems you forgot to define the environment variable on your heroku app instance for `MONGOLAB_URI` and the app is naturally picking up the default, which has been defined as `localhost`

Comment: I set my config variables in heroku to the string but even when I do not use the variables at all (i.e., place the string in directly), it still gets the same error...  When I run the app locally it says it gets a connection. When I push it to heroku, it doesnt...

Comment: You need took in your code to see where `MONGOLAB_URI` is defined. The definition is not shown in the listing here. Common practice is that we pick up such a thing from `process.env` or similar, and usually supply a default. Your error is "telling you" that you have not in fact picked up the value you think you have. If it should be coming from an environment variable, then you need to check your heroku configuration to see that you actually defined it. If you are still confused, then show the code where the variable gets declared.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I did that and replaced MONGOLAB_URI with process.env.MONGOLAB_URI and the error has not changed. The variable is declared in the config vars in heroku. I know it is called appropriately because console.logged it.

Comment: Third time now that I am asking you to actually show the relevant code where this is defined. Don't talk about it. What you actually have needs to be in your question, so people can actually see it. Help us help you. Show the things you have been asked to show.

Comment: sorry. the code was defined in heroku... i can't copy and paste it like I did with the above... and I feel stupid... i started to look for other instances where I may have called mongo but there was this tidbit of code store: new mongoStore({
        url: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
        collection: 'sessions'
    }) and it was able to connect